# Python2.7 pyodbc - content is encoded in unicode instead of utf-8

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7

We are fetching data from our posgresql DB using python2.7 and pyodbc.

The DB is set up with utf-8.

```
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 <db_name>   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
```

Both client and server encoding are set to utf-8:

```
SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING;
 client_encoding
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)


SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;
 server_encoding
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
```

The connection is configured as follows:

```
con.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
con.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
con.setencoding(str, encoding='utf-8')
con.setencoding(unicode, encoding='utf-8')
```

However, the returned data is in unicode and not utf-8.
Any advise on what is missing to get this to work?

Comment: "Unicode" is not an encoding. "UTF-8" is one encoding of Unicode. Can you be more specific regarding to the exact nature of your problem?

Comment: Returned value type is 'unicode' (any text column, table names etc), we need it to  type 'str'.